# problem to send a file path with whitespace as argument

Tags: c#

in my program i want to send a file path with white space in it as argument of cmd
its like this:

```
string command ="a.exe  -ds=datastore1 -dm=thin -n=test    C:\\c d\\a b\\Desktop\\win7.ova    vi://root:@192.168.1.10:443"
restore(command);
 public void restore(string command)
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
            Verb = "runas",
            Arguments = "/C " + command,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
 };
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmdbac = new Process();
        cmdbac.StartInfo = startInfo;
           cmdbac.Start();
            cmdbac.BeginOutputReadLine();
            cmdbac.WaitForExit();
}
```

as you see my path has white spaces-
i have test everything like escape the path as below ..... but my program dont run

i test below

escape with ((\"))

```
string command = "a.exe  -ds=datastore1 -dm=thin -n=test    \"C:\\c d\\a b\\Desktop\\win71.ova\"    vi://root:@192.168.207.128:443"
```

i escape whole command with ((\")) but this dont work too

```
string command = "\"a.exe  -ds=datastore1 -dm=thin -n=test    C:\\c d\\a b\\Desktop\\win71.ova    vi://root:@192.168.207.128:443\""
```

when i run this command in cmd(command line) it will be run

```
a.exe  -ds=datastore1 -dm=thin -n=test    "C:\\c d\\a b\\Desktop\\win71.ova"    vi://root:@192.168.207.128:443
```

but in my program although i escape the path with (\") it will not run

Comment: Why use runas when you don't appear to include any user/password in the command? Looks to me like you can just run it with a.exe as the process name and command (without the a.exe) as the argument

Comment: eg `new ProcessStartInfo{FileName = "a.exe", Arguments = @"-ds=datastore1 -dm=thin -n=test    ""C:\c d\a b\Desktop\win71.ova"" vi://root:@192.168.207.128:443"...` and make sure a.exe is on the path or specify the full location of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the version of `command` where you have wrapped the path in quotes then

Change
`Arguments = "/C " + command`

to:
`Arguments = "/S /C \"" + command + "\""`

Comment: wooooow!!!!!!!!!thank you DCAggie -after many hours of trying and searching this solve my problem- can you describe what is /s and /c  and info about this method

Comment: By using /S and wrapping your command in quotes it will preserve the inner quotes that wrap your path.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd